# Got a Fatal Error when validating a rdf

Tags: web, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, cardinality

I Put the code that is shown below in a rdf vaildator
http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/
and got an (FatalError: The entity "xsd" was referenced, but not declared) i am not sure why i got this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:owl ="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">

<owl:Restriction>
  <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasParent" />
  <owl:cardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">2</owl:cardinality>
</owl:Restriction>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 2):

> *[I got a] (FatalError: The entity "xsd" was referenced, but not declared) i am not sure why i got this.*

In this line:

```xml
<owl:cardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">2</owl:cardinality>
```

the entity `&xsd;`appears.  It wasn't defined, though.  You could resolve the issue by replacing `&xsd;` with `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#`.  E.g.,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:owl ="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">

<owl:Restriction>
  <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasParent" />
  <owl:cardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">2</owl:cardinality>
</owl:Restriction>
</rdf:RDF>
```

That said, it looks like you copied a snippet from an OWL ontology.  The ontology probably had the entity declaration in the origin.  Note that the content you have now is no longer a legal OWL ontology because it doesn't have the property declaration for hasParent, and perhaps because there's no base IRI defined.  It can be still legal RDF, though.